# enable script when press button in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can I enable and disable script on enemy object when I pressed specific button in unity

```
void OnButtonClick()
{
    StartCoroutine(Cooldown());
    GetComponent<FollowEnemy>().enabled = !GetComponent<FollowEnemy>().enabled;
}
```

Comment: What is not working in your code? In general you should cache the result of `GetComponent`

Answer (score 0):

```
GetComponent(MyScript).enabled = false;
```

Might be a good place to start,

For the button a `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)`, would do the trick.

You might need to experiment a bit, you can find more information here:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/26844/enabledisable-specific-components.html

Official documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html